# if statement resets the position of an object... why?

Tags: if-statement, swift, xcode6

When adding this if statement:

```
    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
        stateLabel.text = "Coordniates: \(sender.view!.center.x), \(sender.view!.center.y)"
    }
```

the position of my "panView" resets to it's original position (where it starts when app is started). If I delete the if statement, everything works as intended (the "panView"box stays where I dropped it. The coordinates are updated correctly in the "stateLabel" all the time...

Seams like I'm reseting the position by including the if statement :-o

Any idea?

Here's my complete code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var panView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var stateLabel: UILabel!

let panRec = UIPanGestureRecognizer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    panRec.addTarget(self, action: "draggedView:")
    panView.addGestureRecognizer(panRec)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


func draggedView(sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(sender.view!)
    var translation = sender.translationInView(self.view)

    sender.view!.center = CGPointMake(sender.view!.center.x + translation.x, sender.view!.center.y + translation.y)

    sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)

    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
        stateLabel.text = "Coordniates: \(sender.view!.center.x), \(sender.view!.center.y)"
    }


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}   
}
```

Comment: 1. That worked, but I really want the Auto Layout since I want this to run on several devices.

Comment: 2. Not sure I understand how this is done. If I change anything else than the text props, like `stateLabel.backgroundColor`, everything acts normal (when Auto Layout is enabled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto Layout is moving your view.  You have 2 choices with how to deal with this:

1. Turn off Auto Layout in the File Inspector on the right in Xcode.
2. Work within the Auto Layout system by creating constraints for the horizontal position and vertical position of your view.  If you create the constraints in Interface Builder, add `IBOutlet`s to your constraints in your code, and then update the constraints' `constant` property instead of referencing the frame.

---

Here is your code updated to use constraints.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var panView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var stateLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var panViewCenterX: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var panViewCenterY: NSLayoutConstraint!

    let panRec = UIPanGestureRecognizer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        panRec.addTarget(self, action: "draggedView:")
        panView.addGestureRecognizer(panRec)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    func draggedView(sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(sender.view!)
        var translation = sender.translationInView(self.view)

        panViewCenterY.constant += translation.y
        panViewCenterX.constant += translation.x

        sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)

        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
            stateLabel.text = "Coordniates: \(panViewCenterX.constant), \(panViewCenterY.constant)"
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }   

}
```

---

Now I'm going to walk you through step by step in creating the constraints in Interface Builder.  Don't let the detail scare you, it's not that hard.

1. Click on your Pan View item in *Interface Builder*, and then click on the *Resolve Autolayout Issues* icon at the bottom of the screen <kbd>|-^-|</kbd>.  In the pop up under *Selected Views*, click on *Clear Constraints*.  This makes sure we are starting with a clean slate with regards to constraints for your Pan View.
2. <kbd>Control</kbd> drag diagonally within your Pan View.

[image: first control drag]

3. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and don't let go until I tell you.  In the pop up, click Width and click Height.  Let go of <kbd>Shift</kbd>. Hit <kbd>Return</kbd>.  That set up width and height constraints for your Pan View.

[image: set width and height]

4. <kbd>Control</kbd> drag from the center of your Pan View to the containing View.

[image: second control drag]

5. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and don't let go until I tell you.  In the pop up, click *Leading Space to Container Margin* and click *Top Space to Layout Guide*.  Let go of <kbd>Shift</kbd>. Hit <kbd>Return</kbd>.  That set up horizontal and vertical position constraints for your Pan View.  Now lets change those constraints so that they are based upon the Center X and Center Y of your Pan View.
6. Open the *Document Outline View*.  You may have to turn some triangles to see your new constraints.

[image: document outline]

7. Click on the *Vertical Space* constraint.
8. In the *Size Inspector* on the far right, change *First Item Field* to *Center Y*.  Change *constant* to 100.

[image: constraint inspector]

9. In the *Document Outline View* again, click on the *Horizontal Space* constraint.
10. In the *Size Inspector* on the far right, change *First Item Field* to *Center X*.  Change constant to 100.
11. Wire up the constraints to your code like so:

[image: wire up constraint]

12. Compile and run.  Your Pan View should be draggable and your label should update when you let go.

Comment: Did exactly what you showed and copied the code, but keep getting this error at `panView.addGestureRecognizer(panRec)`: "Thread1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXCI386_INVOP,subcode=0x0). And in the debug area it says: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)".... Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Found the error; I've forgot to wire up the panView :-o Now everything is working!!! Thanx

Comment: Just one more thing: If I want to have more than one `panView` to move around independently, how can that be done easily?

Comment: Looks like stackoverflow wants me to make an new discussion about this, so I'll do that ;-)